# Spring RestTemplate - How to set connect timeout and read time out

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using spring 3.0.5 version of RestTemplate 
Can any one help me .how to set connecttimeout and readTimeout values for each request

but in latest versions there is a solution with HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory   class .but i need with spring.web.3.0.5 version

Answer (score 10):

```
private void setTimeout(RestTemplate restTemplate, int timeout) {
    //Explicitly setting ClientHttpRequestFactory instance to     
    //SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory instance to leverage 
    //set*Timeout methods
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory());
    SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory rf = (SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory) restTemplate
            .getRequestFactory();
    rf.setReadTimeout(timeout);
    rf.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
}
```

Comment: In my version these methods are not availabale

Comment: Please clarify what version do you use ? Its possible that your default request factory is not SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory. In that case, you might encounter run-tim issues as well. So, set the requestFactory for your RestTemplate to SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory as restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory()) before invoking the method I explained

Comment: we are using Spring -web 3.0.5 version, so in that above methods are not available

Comment: It is possible that your RestTemplate could be using and instance of ClientHttpRequestFactory other than SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory. You could try explicitly setting this at the beginning of this method. I shall edit the code above. You may try it now. Please note that SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory is available for 3.0 onwards and hence you won't face any issues.

Comment: Yes Balaji  SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory  is available from  version 3.0. onwards. but in that version  rf.setReadTimeout(timeout);
        rf.setConnectTimeout(timeout);  methods are not available

Comment: I see that these methods available from 3.0.6 onwards. You could try upgrading your artifacts to this version http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/http/client/SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.html

Answer (score 10):

I am using Spring 5.2 and got clean way of setting read and connect timeout settings for RestTemplate object:

```java
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder
            .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(connectTimeoutMillis))
            .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(readTimeoutMillis))
            .build();
    }
```

Comment: does anybody know how to get system timeouts? SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory uses -1 value which means not unlimited, but system defaults.

Comment: @SimonLogic See my answer.

Comment: @SimonLogic Why not ask it as a separate question?

Answer (score 8):

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {

        var factory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();

        factory.setConnectTimeout(3000);
        factory.setReadTimeout(3000);

        return new RestTemplate(factory);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set it in

```
org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory
```

or in another ClientHttpRequestFactory implementation.

To configure it for RestTemplate use

```
restTemplate.setRequestFactory
```

or configure it as bean property.

Answer (score 1):

@SimonLogic I use the following code to print timeouts to log. And of course you can modify it to return them back to caller.

```java
@Slf4j
public class RestTemplateInspectionUtil {
  public static void inspectTimeouts(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    try {
      var requestFactory = restTemplate.getRequestFactory();
      if (requestFactory instanceof AbstractClientHttpRequestFactoryWrapper) {
        Field requestFactoryField = AbstractClientHttpRequestFactoryWrapper.class.getDeclaredField("requestFactory");
        requestFactoryField.setAccessible(true);
        requestFactory = (ClientHttpRequestFactory) requestFactoryField.get(requestFactory);
      }
      if (requestFactory instanceof HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory) {
        HttpClient httpClient = ((HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory) requestFactory).getHttpClient();
        Method createRequestConfigMethod =
            HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.class.getDeclaredMethod("createRequestConfig", Object.class);
        createRequestConfigMethod.setAccessible(true);
        RequestConfig requestConfig = (RequestConfig) createRequestConfigMethod.invoke(requestFactory, httpClient);
        log.debug("socket (read) timeout: {}, connection timeout: {}, connection request timeout: {}",
            requestConfig.getSocketTimeout(), requestConfig.getConnectTimeout(), requestConfig.getConnectionRequestTimeout());
      } else if (requestFactory instanceof SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory) {
        Field readTimeoutField = requestFactory.getClass().getDeclaredField("readTimeout");
        readTimeoutField.setAccessible(true);
        Field connectTimeoutField = requestFactory.getClass().getDeclaredField("connectTimeout");
        connectTimeoutField.setAccessible(true);
        int readTimeout = readTimeoutField.getInt(requestFactory);
        int connectTimeout = connectTimeoutField.getInt(requestFactory);
        log.debug("read timeout: {}, connection timeout: {}", readTimeout, connectTimeout);
      }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      log.debug("Failed to check restTemplate timeouts: {}", ex);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alternative solution (issue with spring_web-3.0.5),like 
The spring RestTemplate class internally uses the HttpClient.java (commons-httpClients-3.1.jar) by constructing CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory, so you can configure it for setting the property connectionTimeOut  and  soTimeout . see the configuration

```
<bean id="httpClient" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient">
 <constructor-arg>
  <bean  class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager">
   <property name="params">
   <bean      class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpConnectionManagerParams">
    <property name="connectionTimeout" value="2000" />
     <!-- <property name="soTimeout" value="2000" />
     soTimeout is same as readTimeout which is used for socket timeout that  waiting for data -->
     </bean>
   </property>
  </bean>
 </constructor-arg>
 </bean>
  <bean id="httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory"
    class="org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory">
  <constructor-arg ref="httpClient" />
   <property name="readTimeout" value="2000"/>
   </bean>

<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
<constructor-arg ref="httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:  Create a function

```
private ClientHttpRequestFactory getClientHttpRequestFactory() {
    int timeout = 5000;
    RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
      .setConnectTimeout(timeout)
      .setConnectionRequestTimeout(timeout)
      .setSocketTimeout(timeout)
      .build();
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder
      .create()
      .setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
      .build();
    return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client);
}
```

Step 2:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(getClientHttpRequestFactory());
```